# What are all the possible commands on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: command-line, bash, ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to figure what commands are available in Ubuntu Touch before I think about installing it on my phone.

I've figured out that `apt-get` is there. But what about `dd`, `top` and `ssh` etc., etc.?

Can someone give me a list?  It should be as simple as typing in the terminal:

```
ls /usr/bin/
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the exact answer but here's how you would find out...

```
find ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -printf "%f\n" | sort -u
```

Assuming you have `find` and `sort`. This will return every executable file in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you Oli, even though this does not answer my question, it is still a nice example of how to find the commands. And also thank you again Oli for trying to be helpful to so many people on askubuntu.com